# Asymptotic probability of a tie in a dice-throwing competition

Tags: probability, asymptotics

We throw a dice $n$ times. Each time it falls on 1 I win, each time it falls on 6 you win; otherwise nobody wins.

What is the probability that both of us win the same number of times, as a function of $n$, when $n$ is very large?

I tried to solve the question using the [multidimensional central-limit-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT). Suppose we throw a single dice. Let $X$ be a random vector of length 6, such that $X_i=1$ if the dice lands on $i$ and 0 otherwise. This is a random vector with (for $p=1/6$):
$$
\mu = [p,p,p,p,p,p]
$$
$$
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p-p^2 & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2 
\\
-p^2 & p-p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2 
\\
-p^2 & -p^2  & p-p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2 
\\
-p^2 & -p^2  & -p^2  & p-p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2 
\\
-p^2 & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & p-p^2  & -p^2 
\\
-p^2 & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & -p^2  & p-p^2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $S$ be a vector that is the sum of $n$ such vectors.
Then, for every $i$ between 1 and 6, $S_i$ is the number of times the dice falls on $i$. When $n$ is sufficiently large, the vector $S$ is distributed like a normal random vector, with mean vector $n\mu$ and covariance matrix $n\Sigma$.

Now, the probability that $S_1=S_6$ is approximately this integral:

$$
\int_{S_1=S_6} f(S)
$$

where $f$ is the probability-density-function of the normal distribution with mean $n\mu$ and covariance $n\Sigma$:

$$
f(S) = 
{
\exp\left(-{1\over 2} (S-n\mu)^T(n\Sigma)^{-1}(S-n\mu)\right)
\over
\sqrt{(2\pi)^6 |n\Sigma|} 
}
$$

I calculated $|\Sigma|$ and it is $p^6(1-6 p) = 0$, so $\Sigma$ does not have an inverse. How can I solve the integral then?

I do not need an exact solution - just an asymptotic solution for large $n$.

Comment: A multinomial vector has one less degree of freedom then its dimension because its entries are linearly dependent - the sum of them must equal to $n$, the number of trials.

Comment: @BGM yes, that's why they are dependent. But what does it say about the probability?

Comment: I am explaining why the covariance matrix is not full rank and you cannot take the inverse. The term "linearly dependent" here is the term in linear algebra - they are not only dependent, but once you know the values of $n-1$ of them, you can completely determine the value of the last one. We call this a degenerate distribution. For the exact asymptotic you just follow the post stated in above comment.